# Is there a way to remove or modify a xlsx (Excel) chart in Python using openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, charts, openpyxl, xlsx

I can't find a way to modify or remove an existing Excel graph in an existing workbook.

That's the only code I could achieve:

```
from openpyxl.chart import AreaChart, Reference, Series
import openpyxl as opyxl

def CreateGraphAC(wb, ws, rows, columns):
    chart = AreaChart()
    chart.title = "Area Chart"
    chart.style = 13
    chart.x_axis.title = 'Test'
    chart.y_axis.title = 'Percentage'

    cats = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_row=rows)
    data = Reference(ws, min_col=2, min_row=1, max_col=columns, max_row=rows)

    chart.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)
    chart.set_categories(cats)

    ws.add_chart(chart, "F1")
    wb.save('test.xlsx')

wb = opyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')
allSheetNames = wb.sheetnames
ws = wb.active
CreateGraphAC(wb, ws, 2, 2)
```

The only thing I discovered is that you can get the list of graphs on a worksheet with:

```
ws._charts
```

Any suggestions? Thank you all in advance.

Comment: `ws._charts` is where you should look. It's a currently a private API because we've not worked out how existing charts should be handled but they are openpyxl chart objects.

Comment: Is there a way to move `ws._charts[0]` to another row and column? If yes, then I solved the problem. Or is it possible to delete ws._charts[0]?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you mean the position of the chart, yes, just change the anchor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by myself

Use `del worksheet._charts[number]` with a `workbook.save('file.xlsx')` and create a new chart with modified parameters.